# Does autofocus work on html span tag?

Tags: html, angular

How can we enable auto focus on an html span tag? I tried using .focus() to make it work instead of autofocus attribute but this doesn't work either.

```
<span class="newCheckbox"  tabindex="0"  #compareSpan (load)="compareSpan.focus()">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
//component
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core'; //import ViewChild if not already done

@ViewChild('compareSpan') cs; //select your span

ngAfterViewInit() {            
        this.cs.nativeElement.focus(); //focus it at after view initialization 
    }
```